# How to create a Shape with two Circles in it?

Tags: java, javafx

I have created a ListView where is dynamically draws a circle of a certain color based on the objects fields. The cell can have three states, exported, has mandatory info, does not have either. The first two they have their own circle color, I would like "doesn't have either" to implement both of their graphics *Two circles*. The problem is you can only set one graphic for a cell.

I tried finding a workaround, by changing the centerX of a circle and using Shape.union on both of them, but it only displays circEx. Is there any way to implement this?

```
listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<BusinessCard>, ListCell<BusinessCard>>(){
                    @Override
                    public ListCell<BusinessCard> call(ListView<BusinessCard> list){
                        return new ColorCell();
                    }
});



//Colors circled that indicates status of card on listView
static class ColorCell extends ListCell<BusinessCard> {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(BusinessCard item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        //Probably should have one circle and setFil in if statements
        Circle circMan = new Circle(0,0,3,Color.web("#ff9999"));
        Circle circEx = new Circle(10,0,3,Color.web("#808080"));  // old #e1eaea 
        Circle circDone = new Circle(0,0,3,Color.web("#99ff99")); //old #99ff99    

         if(item != null){
             setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
             setText(item.toString());

             if(item.wasExported() && !item.hasMand()){
                 setGraphic(Shape.union(circMan, circEx)); //TODO
             }               
             else if(item.wasExported()){
                 setGraphic(circEx);
             }              
             else if(!item.hasMand()){
                 setGraphic(circMan);
             }
             else{
                 setGraphic(circDone);
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you make one circle that's half one color and half the other?

Comment: Hmm, I'll see if I can have two arcs and create a shape from the union between the two, although I do want the two circles I guess this will have to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Pane` as `graphic`, e.g. `HBox`.

Also you should probably not recreate the circles over and over again in the `updateItem` method.

```
static class ColorCell extends ListCell<BusinessCard> {

    private final Circle manDone = new Circle(3);
    private final Circle ex = new Circle(3);
    private final HBox circles = new HBox(4, manDone, ex);

    private static final Color EXPORTED_COLOR = Color.web("#808080");
    private static final Color MAN_COLOR = Color.web("#ff9999");
    private static final Color DONE_COLOR = Color.web("#99ff99");

    {
        setGraphic(circles);

        // hide circles
        manDone.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        ex.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(BusinessCard item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (item == null) {
            // hide circles
            manDone.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            ex.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            setText(null);
        } else {
            setText(item.toString());

            ex.setFill(item.wasExported() ? EXPORTED_COLOR : Color.TRANSPARENT);
            manDone.setFill(item.hasMand()
                               ? (item.wasExported() ? DONE_COLOR : Color.TRANSPARENT)
                               : MAN_COLOR);
        }
    }
}
```